# Java Sockets Local Connection Between 2 clients - Design

Tags: java, sockets

I have an application where the user (client #1) enters a local ip and a port and the application sends a picture to client #2 (who is also using the same application). However for the final application, I do not want the user to enter the local ip because they will not know this information, and I want my program to automatically figure this out.

My first idea:
Originally, I thought that I could scan all the local ip's for an open port, but this would take way too long.

My second idea:
My next idea was to have the clients send their local hostnames to a remote server which then swaps them and sends them back to the clients.

However, I do not want to run a dedicated server for my second idea.

Because this is more of a design question, I am not including any code but I will do so if necessary.

Do you guys have any ideas on how I should design my application to automatically figure out the local ips?

I did try to google this but couldn't figure out a solution, and so I gave up after an hour and just put my question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like [jgroups](http://jgroups.org) (allowing discovery based on multicast [lan] etc) or some [peer-to-peer](http://jxta.kenai.com/) implementatons for that, although the latter require at least some servers for initial discovery.

in principle that works the way, that the clients send a message out to "the world" using some well known address and wait for someone to answer. each client itself waits meanwhile for such a message and replies it with information how to "connect" to the current client. This can be done via a so called blackboard, where this bb is either a special tcp-address for multicast-messages (the os/tcp sends the message to all clients listening concurrently) or one or more servers (seeds) that take and coordinate the request and the "membership" lists. anyway, there are some tools ;)

Comment: So for this to be necessary, the client has to send some information to some pre-known address? Sorry, I'm a little confused :) If I do that, then wouldn't it follow my second idea where it sends the information to a dedicated server? On a related note, is there a quick way to scan open ports on the network? I think UDP is quicker than TCP so perhaps my application could open a UDP port only for the scanning?

Comment: partially ;) if the address is some multicast address (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast) you do not need a dedicated server - at least not in your local network. see the jgroups link above for more on this. for wider networks, one or more well known server (ips/ports) would be good at least for the initial discovery of the running clients. udp/tcp is secondary here..